# How to bulk-select only pivot tables using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models with *many-to-many* relationship defined between them: `User` and `Post`. I need to access **all of the user's posts' pivot table records**. How can I achieve this? For example:

```php
$user->posts()->pivot()->get(); // I need to do something like this
```

The reason why I need this, is to perform a bulk-update in one query on those pivots. Illustration example:

```php
// set 'times_seen' to 100 for all of the pivot records
$user->posts()->pivot()->update(['times_seen' => 100]);
```

Comment: What pivot tables? You have only one pivot table. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to select all of the **records** of pivot table

Comment: Do you need just IDs or also collections of User and Post models?

Comment: I need all the pivot records that belong to this particular user. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, I'm not sure what you really need so please provide more details.

Data from **pivot** table is available in **$pivot** attribute of related model, so you can access it with the following:

```
foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
  echo $post->pivot->someFieldFromPivotData;
}
```

You can find more info on how to work with pivot tables in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

The most efficient way to update all related pivot rows is to directly operate on that table:

```
// to set to fixed value
DB::table('pivot_table_name')->where('user_id', $user->id)->update(['times_seen' => 1]); 

// to increment by one
DB::table('pivot_table_name')->where('user_id', $user->id)->increment('times_seen');
```

Comment: I want to bulk-update the pivot records in one sql query. Iterating through each one of them would be inefficient

Comment: For example: `times_seen` field

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. You have answered my question perfectly for the 3rd time for today, Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The pivot table usually has just two foreign keys used for connection of two models. If you need to get all posts of specified user, you can do this with `$user->posts()`.

> I want to bulk-update the pivot records in one sql query. Iterating through each one of them would be inefficient

If understood you correctly, you want to use `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` with an array:

```
$user->roles()->detach([1, 2, 3]);

$user->roles()->attach([1, 2, 3]);

$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you for answer, but that's not what I am looking for. What I want is, for example, to update a `times_seen` field for every pivot

Comment: Click the link in my answer. You can do `$user->roles()->attach([1 => ['expires' => $expires], 2, 3]);` and I guess that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I've been pretty vague with my question. Thank you for your time